# Mongoose Instance not saving to the database,no error is being shown

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to save a model to mongodb. Although it's not showing any error,the instance is not being saved to db.The object is being properly populated as you can see the output of console.What could be the issue?

```
Model
------
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config/database');
const HospitalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    specialization:{type:String,required:true},
    location:{type:String,required:true},
    address:{type:String,required:true},
    pointOfContact:[{
        name:{type:String,required:true},
        phone:{type:String,required:true}
    }]
})
const Hospital = module.exports = mongoose.model('Hospital',HospitalSchema);
module.exports.addHospital = function(hospital,callback){
    console.log(hospital);
    hospital.save(callback);
}


controller
----------
router.post('/hospital/addHosp',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
  let hospital = new Hospital({
    name:req.body.hosp.name,
    specialization:req.body.hosp.specialization,
    location:req.body.hosp.location,
    address:req.body.hosp.completeAddress,
    pointOfContact:req.body.hosp.pointOfContact,
});

Hospital.addHospital(hospital,(err,hosp)=>{
  (err)=>{console.log(err);res.json({success:false,msg:'failed to add hospital'})},
  (hosp)=>{res.json({success:true,msg:'successfully added hospital'})}
})

})
```

The output of console.log in addHosp function in model:

```
{ _id: 5d3806a53b0d4215ac6bac53,
  name: 'h',
  specialization: 's',
  location: 'l',
  pointOfContact:
   [ { _id: 5d3806a53b0d4215ac6bac54, name: 'n', phone: '99999' } ] }
```

Comment: try hospital.save();, without callback..

Comment: hospital.save() didn't solve the problem but showed me where the error is. Thank you.So the error occurred as I was not passing the hospital address properly from front-end.

Comment: I am happy  that you could figure out the issue ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your function like this one:

```
module.exports.addHospital = function(hospital,callback){
    var hosp = new Hospital(hospital)
    console.log(hosp);
    hosp.save(callback);
}
```